# Gateway Unreachable in Power Bi Service

Tags: powerbi, gateway, power-bi-report-server

this is my first time working with Power BI Service and I'm having trouble configuring the gateway.
I'm using the standard On-premises data gateway and I was able to upload the report I wanted to the service successfully. The gateway appears to be working fine, as shown here:[Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iD2L.png)
And so does the database connection:
[Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTNJV.png)
However, when I try updating the data for my report, I get this error:
Error del origen de datos: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} Table: gestion_banco.
URI de clúster: WABI-SOUTH-CENTRAL-US-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Identificador de actividad: da7400dd-dac2-451a-8f21-a3e6d7bd0905
Identificador de la solicitud: f666bae8-e8a3-cb64-eafa-8bbbb2e4b450
Hora: 2023-09-14 17:47:32Z

I have the most recent version of the gateway. We've uninstalled and installed the gateway a few times already, and we've tried using an entirely new gateway and we end up stuck at the same error. I read that the issue might be related to ports being blocked, but the gateway app is in Spanish and I can't scroll down to the port test section... I've been trying to set it up in English, but nothing has really worked.

[Configuration Gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLRoT.png)
Please help, this is the last thing I need in order to complete this project.

Resolve my problem, and learn Power Bi Service